# Is it possible to get top.location.href when the top frame is on another domain in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I just noticed we have been having a bug when we've been using:

```
top.location = top.location.href;
```

To refresh the outer page. However it seems that Chrome doesn't give you a `top.location` or `parent.location` object with properties when the frame is on a different domain. Is there any workaround? This works fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this seem to accomplish what I want:

```
top.location.href = ""
```